# Garbage keeps getting inserted into the IIS Reverse Proxy URL

Tags: iis-8

I have an IIS reverse proxy using URL Rewrite and ARR on windows 2012 from a ColdFusion app to a .NET application on Windows 2012. The app works in all environments except production.
Here is the expected URL https://www.example.com/foldera/folderb/test.aspx This is what we are getting.
https://www.example.com/foldera/folderb/(S(avwmi0wjsktpt3ewd5hlcztd))/test.aspx

I have turned off the McAfee anti-virus. I have looked at the Dynamic IP Restrictions module in IIS. Nothing there. Thoughts on how to determine what might be causing this?

Comment: That's called cookieless session, https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/627029/Cookieless-Session-in-ASP-NET